# Could subview.origin use the negative coordination?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'd like to ask whether the subview.origin's coordination could be negative or not?

When I use the function below to relocate my subview's frame, for example, from (0, 0, width, height) to (0, -200, width, height) and use NSLog to print out the final frame.origin.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
               animations:^{
                   self.sub.frame = CGRectMake(0, -200, width, height);
               }
               completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                   NSLog(@"(%f, %f)", self.sub.frame.x, self.sub.frame.y);
               }];
```

It is confusing to find that the output is still (0, 0)!

So, is that the origin of the subview is limited in the parent's view?

Thanks in advance sincerely!!!!!

**Solution：**

The main problem is that the view created from storyboard selects "use auto layout" in default. That will disable the function above. Unselect it will solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course!

Try to give some delay, and the view will get negative coordinates

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
                     animations:^{
                         self.sub.frame = CGRectMake(0, -200, width, height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.001 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"(%f, %f)", self.sub.frame.x, self.sub.frame.y);
         });
     }];
```

Comment: It seems not work! Maybe the situation of my app is more complicated.

Comment: I have tried the example, it works fine (you can create a new project and test on it). that means the problem comes from another piece of code

Comment: Additonnal... :  It seems not work! Maybe the situation in my app is more complicated. I move the parent view to (0, -200) in keyboardWillShow:, and move it back in keyboardWillHide:. I execute the following code in a button action: [messageField resignFirstResponder]; codes above;. Is there anything wrong? Thanks!